# Updating Pie Chart with Specific colors not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

Looking at this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gs6rehnx/2106/), there are four arcs with four different colors. I expect the Pie Chart to have three colors after clicking the update button. However, there are still four arcs. I assue, the mapping of the *specific*  colors to the `values` is not working properly? Or is something else not working?

```js
const chart = {};
const duration = 750;
const width = 160;
const height = 160;

const min = Math.min(width, height);
const oRadius = min / 2 * 0.9;
const iRadius = min / 2.5 * 0.85;

const pie = d3
  .pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .sort(null);

const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(oRadius)
  .innerRadius(iRadius);

function arcTween(a) {
  const i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
};

const labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
const color = ["rgba(126,211,33,1)", "rgba(39,173,232,1)", "rgba(229,5,1,1)", "rgba(245,166,35,1)"];

const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(labels)
  .range(color);

const create = function(data) {
  const svg = d3
    .select('.foo')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'pie')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('id', 'svgClass');

  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')')
    .attr('id', 'bar');

  draw(data);
}

const draw = function(data) {
  const path = d3.select('#bar')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data))

  path
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', (d, i) => {
      return scale(d.data.name)
    });

  path
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attrTween('d', function(d) {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate({
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 0
      }, d);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    });
};

const data = [{
  "name": "1",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "2",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "name": "3",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "4",
  "value": 1
}];

const newData = [{
  "name": "1",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "2",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "name": "3",
  "value": 2
}];

function createPie() {
  create(data)
}

function updatePie() {
  draw(newData)
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
    
<button type="button" onclick="createPie()">Click Me First!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="updatePie()">Update Diagram!</button>
<div class='foo'></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because `d3` has three main parts to a selection:

- enter
- update
- exit

In your example above you're dealing with the `enter`, the `update` isn't quite right and the `exit` is completely missing. This is a really good article from the author discussing [data joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

### Enter

The following grabs all the `new` data elements, and adds a new `g` element for each one.

```
path.enter().append('g')
```

### Exit

The following which you're missing will take all the items in the DOM that are no longer represented in the data, and remove them.

```
path.exit().remove();
```

```js
const chart = {};
const duration = 750;
const width = 160;
const height = 160;

const min = Math.min(width, height);
const oRadius = min / 2 * 0.9;
const iRadius = min / 2.5 * 0.85;

const pie = d3
  .pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .sort(null);

const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(oRadius)
  .innerRadius(iRadius);

function arcTween(a) {
  const i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
};

const labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
const color = ["rgba(126,211,33,1)", "rgba(39,173,232,1)", "rgba(229,5,1,1)", "rgba(245,166,35,1)"];

const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(labels)
  .range(color);

const create = function(data) {
  const svg = d3
    .select('.foo')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'pie')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('id', 'svgClass');

  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')')
    .attr('id', 'bar');

  draw(data);
}

const draw = function(data) {
  const path = d3.select('#bar')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data))

  path
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', (d, i) => {
      return scale(d.data.name)
    });
    
  path.exit().remove();

  path
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attrTween('d', function(d) {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate({
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 0
      }, d);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    });
};

const data = [{
  "name": "1",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "2",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "name": "3",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "4",
  "value": 1
}];

const newData = [{
  "name": "1",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "2",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "name": "3",
  "value": 2
}];

function createPie() {
  create(data)
}

function updatePie() {
  draw(newData)
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
    
<button type="button" onclick="createPie()">Click Me First!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="updatePie()">Update Diagram!</button>
<div class='foo'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the provided article and work my way through!

Comment: @Stophface no problem :)

Comment: Ian, any ideas why this http://jsfiddle.net/gs6rehnx/2115/ won't update properly? Sometimes it deletes the correct colored arcs, sometimes it doesn't. I am not sure why...